# not able to retrieve the value of other rows than the first row from a html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, html-table

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input inside a  tag in html table element through javascript in a MVC view. i have get the respective value of the hidden input which is in a loop,when the the respective row is clicked. I have tried many codes but it returns the value of the first row alone for all the rows in the table. i tried the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

{

```
<tr>
    <td hidden><input value="@item.QuoteId" id="QuoteID" class="QuoteID"> </td>
</tr>
}
```

javascript:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
```

`var quoteid=document.getElementById("#QuoteID").innerHTML`
`alert(quoteid)`;
 `alert($('.QuoteID').val());`
`}`

if my db contains 3 values for quote,say 12,17,18.. it alerts 12 for all the row clicks.. Pls help,I am literally stuck. I have been trying it from 3 days,i cant figure it out. I guess it is some simple mistake from my side. Pls help. I am not able to finish  the work assigned to me because of this simple error.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same id multiple times. The ID has to be **unique**!! To make this to work you could call the unique id, or put a onclick on the specific row and call your function with `this`. In your function you can use `this.value`.

```
<script>
    function ShowMeThePower(myElement) {
        alert(myElement.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
<div onclick="ShowMeThePower(this);">This is great!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3RJVd/

**Edit:**

To satisfy the OP:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="show1" value="test1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="show2" value="test2" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        alert(document.getElementById('show' + i).value);
    }
</script>
```

If you see, it's the same logic. Just be sure to use unique id's.

http://jsfiddle.net/4gMy6/

Comment: but i need to get the value from <td> that is in a loop not a <div> element..  Sorry if my question a silly,pls help

Comment: I tried it,as in the fiddle demo that you have given,I am not getting the iterated values from the loop. still only the first item is alerted.  Your code seems to be the correct logic for my requirement but i dont get the iterated Model values.

Comment: Change `<input value="@item.QuoteId" id="QuoteID" class="QuoteID">` to `<input value="@item.QuoteId" id="QuoteID" class="QuoteID" onclick="showMeThis(this);">` then create a function in javascript where you use `this.value`, just like the example.